Send a chatmessage from an app to a user using GraphApi
I have a software application that needs to send automated notification messages to individual users in Teams.
It's the first time I'm using the GraphAPI. An app was created for me in Azure with a client id and secret.
The authentication is working fine (as application, not a delegated scenario).
I'm trying to figure out which endpoints I need to call to send the chatmessage but facing some missing links. In reverse order:

Send chat message: requires a chat-id
Get chat between user and teamsApp: requires an app-installation-id

So appearently The user needs to install the app first? But this can also be done through API


Install an app for user: requires an app-id

I have no idea where to find this id



Am I going in the right direction with this? Do I need to go for a deligated flow? Should I be using a bot? Any pointers are very much welcome as the documentation is lacking in higher level concepts and structures. Thank you

Are you trying to run POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages query?

@Rukmini, no the POST /chats/{chat-id}/messages I don't think I need a channel or a Team. I want to keep things as simple as possible.

What is your exact requirement and what are you trying to do?

Or do you want to use https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}/chats/{chat-id}/messages?

@Rukmini the only requirement is to send an automated message to a user. Whatever the simplest way to achieve this is fine for me.

Did the check the above query?

Yes but this also requires a chat-id which in its turn requires an app id. So same question as the one I posted in this case

AFAIK to send message to user you must need chatID

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1400755/send-direct-message-to-a-user-via-ms-teams-program

And it required Users chatID not app ID., You can get users chat ID by using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserID/chats URL

I guess you need to switch to delegated flow

We ended up using PowerAutomate to expose a webservice that can send chat message directly to users.

Initially I tried to send the message using token generated with client credentials flow that is as application I got the error like below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/chatID/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
     "content": "Hello world"
  }
}



Note that: To send a chat message to a user from an application, you need to grant delegated API permissions and make use of delegated/user-interactive flows as sending messages with application permissions is not supported. Refer this MsDoc

To send a message to the user, you can make use of POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserId/chats/ChatID/messages query.
To run this query, you will be needing User ID and ChatID.

You can get the user ID from the portal in User tab.
To get the ChatID, you need to run this query GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/chats

The id is the Chat ID of the user:

Now to send message to the user, you need to grant ChatMessage.Send delegated API permission:

Generated auth-code:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=ChatMessage.Send
&state=12345


Generated access token using below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:ChatMessage.Send
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms


I am able to send message successfully using above generated access token:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/chats/ChatID/messages

{
  "body": {
     "content": "Hello world"
  }
}



Reference:
Send direct message to a user via MS Teams programmatically - Microsoft Q&A by Prashant Bali

It seems the delegated authorization requires the user to go through a confirmation page each time they log in. This won't work since I'm trying to send it from an application, it has to be pure API, no user interaction.

To send a chat message to a user from an application, you need to grant delegated API permissions and make use of delegated/user-interactive flows as sending messages with application permissions is not supported. Hence User interaction is must and cant send it from application

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions-for-channel Microsoft supports only user interactive flow for this API

So it is NOT possible to create an integration with a software application that automatically sends a message to a user through GraphAPI?

Yes you are right its not possible as the API itself doesnt support application permissions

You need an app (appId) to be able to send 'proactive messages' in a chat/channel
